# Azure Devops Cordova Command Failing Since Yesterday

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-devops, angular-cli

I am getting the following error using the Ionic Command in VS Devops since yesterday. In the logs the only difference is that the VSTS hosted command is now using `Ionic 4.3.0` by default which was released yesterday.

> 2018-11-01T16:45:56.7262388Z > ng run
>   app:ionic-cordova-build:production --platform=browser
>   2018-11-01T16:45:56.7687163Z 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, 2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818095Z [WARN] Not
>   installing--here's how to install manually: npm i -D -E @angular/cli
>   2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818217Z operable program or batch file.
>   2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818642Z  2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818698Z [INFO]
>   Looks like @angular/cli isn't installed in this project.
>   2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818753Z         2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818815Z
>   This package is required for this command to work properly.
>   2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818842Z  2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818897Z
>   --no-confirm: Install @angular/cli? No 2018-11-01T16:45:56.7818924Z  2018-11-01T16:45:56.7819462Z [ERROR] @angular/cli is required for this
>   command to work properly. 2018-11-01T16:45:56.9840907Z ##[error]Task
>   failed 2018-11-01T16:45:56.9865809Z ##[section]Finishing: Ionic
>   Command cordova build browser --prod

To prove a point I have run a previous build that ran successfully yesterday and is now failing today.

`@angular/cli` is in the `package.json` file. I have also added another npm task to manually install @angular/cli before the Ionic Command runs and I still get the same error.

I originally thought this might be because our packages were out of date but I have updated to Ionic 4.3.0 locally and all builds correctly without issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So this seems to be because Angular/Cli is no longer installed as a global dependency. The ionic command cannot find the dev dependency install that is part of the package.json file. Is anyone else using the Ionic Command in Azure Devops ? The command I am running is . Ionic Command cordova build browser --prod.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to deploy a Ionic PWA on azure, and struggling a bit with all the bits and pieces. Did you follow a specific set of instructions or are you able to provide some quick pointers as on the right direction to go?

Answer (score 1):

So I have got this working for now with a hack, which I think should not be possible.

I created a separate build task to install the `@angular/cli` package but this time with the `-g` flag `install i -g -E @angular/cli@6.2.6`

[image]
This in itself seems like a problem to me as on other build processes I have not been able to do this as it requires higher privileges such as root user in Azure Devops.

So I think this means I have privileges I shouldn't have on the build VM.